# What determines the CP of a transformed Ditto?

Tags: pokemon-go

If a Ditto transforms in battle it changes its CP. Is there a way to predict the resulting CP value?

Does it just copy the base stats of its opponent, which are then put into the CP formula?

It looked like the Ditto kept its own level (and IVs?) but everything else was copied. Which in turn would imply that if the Ditto is at max level with 100% IV, it would always have higher (or equal) CP than the opponent.

I'm also interested in whether it's the same behavior if the Ditto is disguised as a wild Pokemon.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that as far as **CP** is concerned, Ditto simply takes on the base attack, stamina and defense stats of the Pokémon that it transforms into.  These values, along with the Ditto's individual values, are plugged into the [CP formula](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongodev/comments/4t7xb4/exact_cp_formula_from_stats_and_cpm_and_an_update/).

When it comes to **HP**, more research is required.  Other sources are reporting that the HP stays the same, but I have not tested that aspect.

If the Ditto is at the same level as the Pokémon that it transforms into, it should have similar CP. A max level 100% Ditto, should have higher or the same CP as the Pokémon it transforms into.

So the transformed ditto CP formula looks like this:

```
Ditto_transformed_CP = Floor(((transformed_pokemon_base_attack + ditto_attack_iv) 
                       * (transformed_pokemon_base_defense + ditto_defense_iv)^0.5 
                       * (transformed_pokemon_base_stamina + ditto_stamina_iv)^0.5 
                       * (ditto_level_multiplier)^2) / 10)
```

### Testing

#### Test 1

I used a level 10.5 Ditto with 4/11/8 IVs against a Jolteon in a gym, and the Ditto CP changed to 756.

```
Ditto_transformed_CP = Floor(((232+4) * (201+11)^0.5 * (130+8)^0.5 * (0.432926413)^2)/10)
Ditto_transformed_CP = Floor((236 * (212)^0.5 * (138)^0.5 * 0.18742527967914354769) / 10)
Ditto_transformed_CP = Floor((236 * 14.56021978 * 11.74734012 * 0.1874252797) / 10)
Ditto_transformed_CP = Floor((7565.674354) / 10)
Ditto_transformed_CP = Floor(756.5674354)
Ditto_transformed_CP = 756
```

#### Test 2

I used a level 26 13/4/8 IV Ditto against a Tauros, and the CP changed to 1744.

```
Ditto_transformed_CP = Floor(((198+13) * (197+4)^0.5 * (150+8)^0.5 * (0.68116492)^2)/10)
Ditto_transformed_CP = Floor((211 * (201)^0.5 * (158)^0.5 * 0.4639856482) / 10)
Ditto_transformed_CP = Floor((211 * 14.17744688 * 12.56980509 * 0.4639856482) / 10)
Ditto_transformed_CP = Floor(17446.71131 / 10) 
Ditto_transformed_CP = Floor(1744.671131)
Ditto_transformed_CP = 1744
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is the breakdown of Ditto.

Ditto as a defender can be terrible if the attacker uses a Magikarp first.. but if they don't pay attention it could make them struggle a little bit.

As far as attacking, the IV's for attack and defense are copied from the pokemon you transform to, but the health/stamina is not. With that being said, transforming into a chansey/snorlax may not be the best pick as they both don't have very strong attacks. I recommend if needed to use a Ditto, use it on legendaries when they come out, or a pokemon with high attack like a Dragonite. The CP that the ditto gets is based on the current ditto level and the attack/defense stats on the pokemon you transform into. For any pokemon with high stamina ditto will always be much weaker, but for strong attacking pokemon with lower stamina, ditto may be the smarter choice especially if you can't max a dragonite due to not being able to find enough dratini's.

Ditto in the wild: Ditto has appeared as a magikarp, pidgey, rattata, and a zubat. The basic catch rate for all those are 40% or a little higher, while the ditto is 16%. So if you see one breaking out of pokeballs relentlessly, it may be a ditto or just shitty luck.

And a 100% ditto would not have equal or higher CP than what transforming into due to the stamina doesn't transfer over. Most pokemon in gyms you will find aren't maxed for their level, so it just may be the case that your ditto is a higher level than what your attacking.

Also, when transforming a ditto to another pokemon, you can still dodge the first two attacks even while transforming.

Answer (score 2):

so from what I've experimented with, Ditto appears to have a CP multiplier.  As far as I have tested, for dragonite, it is about a 5.1 multiplier.  Lapras is a little lower.  My 344 Ditto turned into a 1752 dragonite, while my 196 ditto turned into a 1001 dragonite.  For lapras, my 344 turned to just over 1400 lapras, while my 196 turned into an 800 lapras, which leads me to believe that it is around 4 times multiplier for lapras.  It did not matter which dragonite I used to fight the ditto, as it stayed the same CP for my 2160 dragonite and my 1500 dragonite.

Answer (score 2):

Ditto is actually a really good defender in a high level gym. If someone wants to make it transform into a magikarp, they have to waste a slot in their party with a magikarp. Since gyms can have up to 10 defenders and an attacker can only use 6 pokemon, wasting one of the attacker's pokemon with a ditto gives the gym an advantage. The only problem is that ditto will almost always be the first pokemon kicked out of a gym, so it's good for the gym but bad for the person who put it in.

From what I've heard, a ditto keeps its own ivs and level, but gets the base stats (attack, defense AND stamina) of the pokemon it turns into. So yes, if you have a maxed out, perfect ditto it will always have a higher cp than its opponent.